# Change the "code" icon in markup editor toolbar?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, markdown, editor

Since a few weeks Stack Overflow has a new icon in the editor toolbar for code markup.

It's a pair of braces (curly brackets) which is much more recognizable than the old [101 010] icon still used here.

I'd like to suggest that the icon is changed here, too.